# Folland, Real Analysis Modern Techniques etc Exercise 3.26

Tags: measure-theory

A measure $\mu$ on the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as regular provided that (1) $\mu(K)<\infty$ for all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and
(2) $\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(U):\text{ $U$ is open and $E\subseteq U$}\}$.

Exercise 3.26 asks to prove that if $\lambda,\nu$ are measures on the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then both $\lambda$ and $\nu$ are regular if
the measure $\lambda+\nu$ is regular and $\lambda\perp\nu$.

I'm puzzled about the condition $\lambda\perp\nu$. The condition
for compact sets is evidently met by both $\lambda$ and $\nu$ if it is met by $\lambda+\nu$. Hence both $\lambda,\nu$ are sigma finite.

If $E$ is Borel measurable that is finite for $\lambda$ and $\nu$, and if $\mathcal E$ is the collection of all
open subsets $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $E\subseteq U$, then by the regularity
of $\lambda+\nu$,
$$\lambda(E)+\nu(E)=\inf_{U\in \mathcal{E}}[\lambda(U)+\nu(U)]\ge\inf_{U\in\mathcal{E}}\lambda(U)+\inf_{U\in\mathcal{E}}\nu(E)\ge \lambda(E)+\nu(E)$$
which implies $\lambda(E)=\inf_{U\in\mathcal{E}}\lambda(U)$ and $\nu(E)=\inf_{U\in\mathcal{E}}\nu(E)$.

The result then extends to an arbitrary measurable set $E$ by writing $E$ as the disjoint union of a sequence $(E_k)^\infty_{k=1}$ of measurable sets, each of which is finite for
$\lambda,\nu$.

Comment: I understand to the point that you prove $\inf_{U\in\mathcal{E}}\lambda(U)+\inf_{U\in\mathcal{E}}\nu(E) = \lambda(E)+\nu(E)$. Why can you conclude from there that $\inf_{U\in\mathcal{E}}\lambda(U) = \lambda(E)$ and $\inf_{U\in\mathcal{E}}\nu(U) = \nu(E)$?

Comment: @Daniel We always have $\lambda(E)\leq \inf_{U\in \mathcal{E}}\lambda(U)$ and likewise for $\nu$. If we had a strict inequality here, then the first equality you wrote down cannot be satisfied. Anyway, to OP: I believe you're right that mutual singularity is a red-herring.

Comment: Could it be that this exercise is meant to work for signed-measures? In that case, your argument would fail because the monotonicity of the measure is not true if the measure is not non-negative

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest your approach doesn't seem to work out and you might have misunderstood the definition of singularity.

A correct proof is as follows. I hope this can be helpful.

Proof. Condition (1) holds trivially. For condition (2), since $\nu\perp\lambda$, suppose $N$ is $\nu$-null and $N^c$ is $\lambda$-null. Since $\lambda+\nu$ is regular, for any $E\subset N$ that is Borel measurable, there exists an open set $U$ such that $\lambda(U)<\lambda(U)+\nu(U)<\lambda(E)+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$, therefore $\lambda$ is regular. The same goes for $\nu$.

Answer (score 0):

William von Schwarz already showed that for any $E \in \mathcal B_{\mathbb R^n}$ $$\lambda (E) = \inf \left \{\lambda (U)\ |\ U\ \text{is open and}\ U \supseteq E \cap N \right \}.$$ To complete the proof it is enough to show that given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists an open set $\mathcal O_{\varepsilon} \supseteq N^c$ in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\lambda (\mathcal O_{\varepsilon}) \leq \varepsilon$ and here is the reason $:$

Having obtained such an open set $\mathcal O_{\varepsilon} \supseteq E,$ the first thing to note is that for every open set $U \supseteq E \cap N,$ the open set $U \cup \mathcal O_{\varepsilon}$ contains $E.$ So by monotonicity of $\lambda$ we have $$\lambda (E) \leq \lambda (U \cup \mathcal O_{\varepsilon}) \leq \lambda (U) + \lambda (\mathcal O_{\varepsilon}) \leq \lambda (U) + \varepsilon.$$ This is true for any open set $U \supseteq E \cap N$ and for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and hence taking infimum over all open sets $U \supseteq E \cap N$ it follows that $\lambda (U \cup \mathcal O_{\varepsilon}) \leq \lambda (E) + \varepsilon.$ Since for any open set $V \supseteq E$ we have $\lambda (E) \leq \lambda (V)$ so it follows from the last equality that $$\lambda (E) = \inf \left \{\lambda (V)\ |\ V\ \text{is open and}\ V \supseteq E \right \}.$$

as required. So we will be done if we can prove the following $:$

> Given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists an open set $\mathcal O_{\varepsilon} \supseteq N^c$ in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\lambda (\mathcal O_{\varepsilon}) \leq \varepsilon.$

Since $\lambda + \nu$ is regular and $\mathbb R^n$ is a countable union of compact sets it follows that $\lambda + \nu$ is $\sigma$-finite. So there is a countable disjoint collection $\{X_j\}_{j \geq 1}$ such that $N^c = \bigsqcup\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} X_j$ and $(\lambda + \nu) (X_j) \lt \infty,$ $\forall j.$ Since $\lambda + \nu$ is regular there exist open sets $\mathcal O_j \supseteq X_j$ such that $\forall j$ $$(\lambda + \nu) (\mathcal O_j) \leq (\lambda + \nu) (X_j) + \frac {\varepsilon} {2^j}.$$ Let $\mathcal O_{\varepsilon} : = \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} \mathcal O_j.$ Then $\mathcal O_{\varepsilon}$ is open, $\mathcal O_{\varepsilon} \supseteq N^c$ and we have

$$\begin{align*} \lambda (\mathcal O_j) & = \lambda (\mathcal O_j \cap N) \\ & = (\lambda + \nu) (\mathcal O_j \cap N) \\ & = (\lambda + \nu) (\mathcal O_j) - (\lambda + \nu) (\mathcal O_j \cap N^c) \\ & \leq (\lambda + \nu) (X_j) + \frac {\varepsilon} {2^j} - \nu (\mathcal O_j \cap N^c) \\ & \leq \nu (X_j) + \frac {\varepsilon} {2^j} - \nu (X_j) \\ & = \frac {\varepsilon} {2^j} \end{align*}$$

and, hence $$\lambda (\mathcal O_{\varepsilon}) \leq \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} \lambda (\mathcal O_j) \leq \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac {\varepsilon} {2^j} = \varepsilon.\ \blacksquare$$